# Problem getting input from loop generated python tk.entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Ive been rewriting all of my code since last night ,for a time card calculator I've been working on, to try to shorten it up and make it more efficient.

So now I've got it so that the `time_in` entry boxes and `time_out` entry boxes are made from a `for loop`. Only issue im having right now is I can't figure out how to get the input from them in the calculate function.

Before I had it written so I have a `variable` name for each box and had a list of all the boxes like `times = [time_in1.get(), time_in2.get(), ect...]`

But since im not doing that, I can't figure out exactly how to get the input.

```
import tkinter as tkr

root = tkr.Tk()

windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)

root.title("Time Card Calculator")
root.geometry( "+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(background='grey14')

entries_in = []
entries_out = []
totals = []

labelfont = ('calibri', 35)
smallfont = ('calibri', 20)
grandtotalfont = ('calibri', 30)

header = tkr.Label(root, text="Time Card Calculator", background="grey14")
header.config(font=labelfont, fg="snow")
header.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

first_name = tkr.Label(root, text="Employee First Name", background="grey14")
first_name.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
first_name.grid(row=1, column=0)

first_name_input = tkr.Entry(root)
first_name_input.config(highlightbackground="grey14")
first_name_input.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15)

last_name = tkr.Label(root, text="Employee Last Name", background="grey14")
last_name.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
last_name.grid(row=1, column=2)

last_name_input = tkr.Entry(root)
last_name_input.config(highlightbackground="grey14")
last_name_input.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=15)

pay_start_label = tkr.Label(root, text="Pay Start", background="grey14")
pay_start_label.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
pay_start_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

pay_start_input = tkr.Entry(root)
pay_start_input.config(highlightbackground="grey14")
pay_start_input.grid(row=4, column=0)

pay_end_label = tkr.Label(root, text="Pay End", background="grey14")
pay_end_label.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
pay_end_label.grid(row=3, column=1)

pay_end_input = tkr.Entry(root)
pay_end_input.config(highlightbackground="grey14")
pay_end_input.grid(row=4, column=1)

pay_date_label = tkr.Label(root, text="Pay Date", background="grey14")
pay_date_label.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
pay_date_label.grid(row=3, column=2)

pay_date_input = tkr.Entry(root)
pay_date_input.config(highlightbackground="grey14")
pay_date_input.grid(row=4, column=2)

time_in_label = tkr.Label(root, text="Time In", background="grey14")
time_in_label.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
time_in_label.grid(row=5, column=0)

time_out_label = tkr.Label(root, text="Time Out", background="grey14")
time_out_label.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
time_out_label.grid(row=5, column=1)

totals_label = tkr.Label(root, text="Total", background="grey14")
totals_label.config(font=smallfont, fg="snow")
totals_label.grid(row=5, column=2)

#=====Creates entry boxes 
for i in range(6, 24):
    entryin = tkr.Entry(root)
    entryin.grid(row=i+1, column=0, padx=15, pady=2)
    entryin.config(highlightbackground="grey14")
    entries_in.append(entryin)

for i in range(6,24):
    entryout = tkr.Entry(root)
    entryout.grid(row=i+1, column=1, padx=15, pady=2)
    entryout.config(highlightbackground="grey14")
    entries_out.append(entries_out)

#=== Creates label to put the totals of the entries into

for i in range(6,24):
    total_label = tkr.Label(root, textvariable="")
    total_label.grid(row=i+1, column=2)
    total_label.config(background="grey14", fg="snow")
    totals.append(total_label)


def clear():
    pass

def calculate():

    totals_in = []

    for time in entries_in:
        if time.get() == str(""):
            time = str('0:0')
        fields = time.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_in.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))

        print(totals_in)

def printer():
    pass

button_clear = tkr.Button(root, width=15, height=2, background="grey14", fg="black",
                          highlightbackground="dodgerblue3", text="Clear", command=clear)
button_clear.grid(row=25, column=0, padx=15, pady=5)

button_calculate = tkr.Button(root, width=15, height=2, background="grey14", highlightbackground="dodgerblue3",
                              text="Calculate", command=calculate)
button_calculate.grid(row=25, column=1, padx=15, pady=5)

button_print = tkr.Button(root, width=15, height=2, background="grey14", highlightbackground="dodgerblue3",
                          text="Print", command=printer)
button_print.grid(row=25, column=2, padx=15, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was such an easy solution. I just had to `.get()` before the `if` statement in the `for loop`

```
def calculate():

    totals_in = []

    for time in entries_in:
        inn = time.get()
        if inn == str(""):
            inn = str('0:0')
        fields = inn.split(":")
        hours = fields[0] if len(fields) > 0 else 0.0
        minutes = fields[1] if len(fields) > 1 else 0.0
        totals_in.append(round(float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60.0), 3))
```